# (basic) Print each letter in Indexing

Tags: python, indexing

```
a = 'Hello World!'
print(a[0])
```

then I will get 'H'.

But is there any way I can get all the letters inside `a` seperately without typing `print` many times?

Comment: `print(a)`? That prints all the letters, and in the correct order too.

Comment: like stated in above comment, use `print(a)` or if you want each index individually then use a loop ( figure out that part yourself )

Comment: Do you want to print each character on a separate line? One easy way to do that is `print('\n'.join(a))`

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
a = 'Hello World!'
print(*a, sep=" ")
```

will print:

```
H e l l o   W o r l d !
```

This code:

```
a = 'Hello World!'
print(*a, sep="\n")
```

will print:

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
!
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to iterate?

```
for letter in a:
    print(letter, end='')
```

This assigns each item in the iterable `a` in turn to the variable `letter` for the duration of the indented block, and executes it as many times as there are items.

Equivalently, you can use an index into the string:

```
for idx in range(len(a)):
    print(a[idx], end='')
```

`range(n)` simply produces the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... *n*-1 (you can optionally make it count from 0 or any other integer, in a different direction, etc).

If you want to keep a newline after each letter, you can take out the `end=''` keyword parameter.